# Can’t login to DD-WRT router with SSH can Telnet

Tags: ssh, putty, dd-wrt

I have TP-link which I re-installed the DD-WRT firmware on TP-Link WR740N
and the firmware version is: `DD_WRT v24-sp2(03/25/13)std -build 21061`

So I can login to router using only web interface and Telnet, but when I use PuTTY to login to DD-WRT router via SSH, PuTTY warning me with this message:

```
Putty Fatal Error 
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you have verified the serial cable your using works with other devices?

Answer (score 2):

[DD-WRT build 21061 is known for SSH problems](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=768261). I had the same problem with my Netgear WNR2200 on this build. Use latest build from [ftp.dd-wrt.com](ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/) instead.